# wordpress java xml rpc library and/or client

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

Can anyone recommend an xml rpc library or client for wordpress using java?
I've run into migration hell moving a joomla install to wordpress.

Main reason for wanting to use rpc now is because i will be using it as my primary way of posting to the blog so i'm putting a simple client together and it needs to be configurable enough to allow me to port my joomla posts.

Some posts in future will just be reports generated from a java program as well so, its kinda essential i get something now if possible.

BTW if anyone understands the current wordpress table structure and can advise on how to do direct mysql inserts then i'm open to that too.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just posted this link on a different WordPress question:
[Database Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) from WordPress Codex. That will help you understand WordPress' table structure.

Your project sounds pretty interesting. A quick google search shows some info on Java and XML-RPC: [1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/j-xmlrpc.html), [2](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/index.html) (javax.xml.rpc ).

Second link belongs to [Apache XML-RPC](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/), probably a good option for your project.

Comment: thanks for the links. The db description has helped.
I'm still looking into the rpc option though since it might be easier than to maintain the various relationships when creating custom fields and categories etc.

Just a question tho, when using rpc, are you essentially posting the formatted xml with your request to the specified url?

Comment: There are API's for that. Check out this link: http://www.franzone.com/2007/08/03/would-you-like-to-post-to-wordpress-from-java/

Comment: Thank you, the database description link has been very very helpful.
I wrote a quick java program to connect directly to mysql and insert a post. I have it inserting a post with custom fields in the post_meta table and i have the relationships right. Everything is in order except for one little thing i'm missing.

When i'm in wordpress and i look at the posts it has everything right,so it has the right category, the correct tags etc but when i click on the categories it still says the amount of posts in all the categories is 0, i'm assuming there is a relationship

Comment: i'm not creating but not sure where i should be doing it, any ideas? thanks for the java api i will probably use both methods to see which works out best.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java , I've just added a few features.

Comment: :) I've already hacked together a simplistic rest client for wordpress that I make requests to but I'll have a look. Might migrate to this if it won't be too time consuming....